# Rounding step in base::rank()?

Tags: r, correlation, ranking, spearman-rho

I have been trying to compare rankings between 2 lists. The list components are random effects from a mixed model, so they are shrunken towards zero and mean-centered as well.

R's base function:

```
cor(x,y,method = "spearman")
```

relies on another base function, rank(), which appears to first convert everything to an integer, the mathematically equivalent of rounding down by dropping everything after a decimal point.

```
# example where ranks and order are identical:

x0<-as.numeric(1:500)
order(x0)
rank(x0)

sum(abs(order(x0) - rank(x0)))

# example where ranks and order differ

set.seed(300)
x1<-rnorm(500,1,50)

order(x1)
rank(x1)
order(as.integer(x1))

sum(abs(order(x1) - rank(x1)))
```

Converting to an integer does flatten out the data by creating more duplicated data points:

```
>length(unique(as.character(as.integer(x1))))
[1] 186
> length(unique(as.character(x1)))
[1] 500
```

Is there any statistical justification for this rounding step? As is, it looks like an unfortunate error to use rank(). Unless I'm missing something (which is what I what I would like to find out from the cross validated folks), by rounding the values, the spearman correlations are overestimated by creating more ties than what actually occurs in the data.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I think you'll need to illustrate the behaviour you're querying for this to be understandable.

Comment: if you're using random numbers, please set the seed so we're sure we have the same objects

Comment: `rank` does not convert its arguments to integers. (You'd be right that the Spearman correlation would be incorrect if it did.)

Comment: The problem you're running into is actually with your understanding of `order`, not `rank`. Try shuffling x0 with `x0 <- sample(1:500, 500)` and see what happens.

Comment: You should use a smaller example such as `set.seed(300); x1<-rnorm(4,1,50)` and study the first sentence in `help("order")` carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Repeating some of the points in the comments:

- `rank()` does not always take integer values
- `order()` always takes integer values though it is not a ranking of the original values but the original location of the sorted values
- `cor(x, y, "method = "spearman")` uses `rank()`

Try the illustration illustration: `rank(x)` and `order(x)` are different both in terms of integers and values while `rank(y)` and `order(y)` misleadingly look the same.  Consider where `2` appears:

- With `rank(x)`, the fifth value is `2` because `x[5]` is the second lowest value of `x`;
- with `order(x)`, the third value is `2` because `x[2]` is the third lowest of `x`.
- With `rank(y)`, the first value is `2` because `y[2]` is the lowest value of `y`;
- with `order(y)`, the first value is  `2` because `y[1]` is the second lowest of `y`.

You can also see that `cor(x, y, method = "spearman")` is based on `rank()` rather than `order()`

```
> x <- c(20,40,50,50,30)
> y <- c(70,60,80,90,110)
> rank(x)
[1] 1.0 3.0 4.5 4.5 2.0
> order(x)
[1] 1 5 2 3 4
> rank(y)
[1] 2 1 3 4 5
> order(y)
[1] 2 1 3 4 5
> cor(x, y, method = "spearman") 
[1] 0.1538968
> cor(rank(x),  rank(y),  method="pearson")
[1] 0.1538968
> cor(order(x), order(y), method="pearson")
[1] 0
```